# How do i validate my phonumber to start with a 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

i have been trying to create a custom validation using data annotations in mvc.
I need to validate that a user enters a phone number that starts with a 0 in a textbox on a view if not they get an error.somehow my logic is wrong
im new to coding and having abit of difficulty pls help.

here is my code

```
     public class FirstNumberAttributes:ValidationAttribute
   {

    public FirstNumberAttributes(int firstdigit)
    {
        _firstdigit = firstdigit;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult isValid(objectvalue,ValidationContext validationContext)           
    {
        if (value!=null)
        {

            var valueAsString = value.ToString();
            if (valueAsString.Substring(0,1)!=_firstdigit)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Number doesnt start with "+_firstdigit);
            }
         }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    private readonly int _firstdigit;
}
```

}

Comment: try: `if (valueAsString.Substring(0,1)!=_firstdigit.ToString())`

Comment: Or you can use a regex to validate your phone number, because i can input a 0 as first digit then mess it all up in the end , make sure there is no letters in the phone number as well

Comment: Use regex for validation to your phone number..

Comment: MVC already has a built-in validation attribute for this - a [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I usually using regular expression to validate phone number. Just use the pattern to what you like to filter it.

```
String pattern = "[" + _firstNumber + "*]"; 
if(Regex.IsMatch("01234567", pattern)){
    return ValidationResult.Success;
}else{
    return new ValidationResult("Number doesnt start with "+_firstNumber);
}
```